# Atom is not highlighting Haskell syntax?

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

I am using Haskell in Atom text editor `version 1.23.1` on Mac. Other languages syntax is highlighted correctly but when I code in Haskell the text editor does not highlight the syntax correctly and shows it as plain text. I have tried searching for it and found that in Atom pressing ***`ctrl-shift-L`*** I can temporarily change the grammar. However, there is no option for Haskell as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: No option for Haskell]

The screenshot below shows what I am expecting.

[image: What I am expecting]

Is there anything that I might have done wrong? Can anyone give me a clear and easy solution to this problem. Thank you

Comment: Is there any plugin to install that provides Haskell support? Maybe it's just not bundled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell support unfortunately doesn't come packaged with atom. Use the [`language-haskell`](https://atom.io/packages/language-haskell) package.

The [`language-haskell`](https://atom.io/packages/language-haskell) package, according to the page *'Adds syntax highlighting and snippets to Haskell files in Atom.'* It comes with support for `.hs`, `.lhs`, and `.cabal` files.

You can find help on installing atom packages [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/).

If you want to talk about adding Haskell support, or changing atom features, it seems that [the atom forum](https://discuss.atom.io/) would be the best place to do so.